# WP7 Reminder with NavigationUri when phone is blocked issue

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1

When `Reminder` created with set path in `NavigationUri` param have such issue:
when phone is blocked (under locked screen) and reminder shown, it's impossible to navigate to the app using Tap on title or content of the reminder message.

Is it possible to solve such problem, or it's ussual behaviour for reminder and lock screen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the normal behavior for Windows Phone 7, the user needs to unlock the phone to interact with notifications. There's nothing you can do about it.

There's a few obvious reasons for this behavior. Imagine that the user has put a pin-code on the lockscreen. Someone picking up the phone would be able to bypass the pin-code by tapping on a notification. Or even if there's no code, I may trigger something involuntarily if the phone is inside my pocket when a notification is displayed.